# PHP error: Query was empty

Tags: php

here is the code that gives me this error. I have searched around, found related questions, but I couldn't apply the implementation. Here is something wrong and it's beyond my understanding..

```
function add_user_to_db()
{
    $dbhost = "111.111.111.111";
    $dbuser = "Bob";
    $dbpass = "password";
    $connection = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    if(!$connection){die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());}
    echo 'Connected to Vikings Game DB!';

    mysql_select_db('vgDB');

    $tb_result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'Players'");
    $table_exists = mysql_num_rows($tb_result) > 0;
    if($table_exists)
    {
        if( isset($_POST["ID"]) && isset($_POST["NAME"]) && isset($_POST["COMMENT"]) )
        {
            $id          = $_POST['ID'];
            $name        = $_POST["NAME"];
            $comment     = $_POST["COMMENT"];

            //Check if a row exists
            $row_result = mysql_query("SELECT `".$id."` FROM Players");
            if($row_result == FALSE)
            {
                $add_user_query = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO Players( ID , NAME , COMMENT )VALUES('123','Bob','Bob's comment')" );
                $retval = mysql_query($add_user_query, $connection);
                if(!$retval) die("Could not insert data: ".mysql_error());
                echo "User '".$id."' was added successfully!";
            }
            else
            { 
               $name_read = mysql_query("SELECT NAME FROM Players WHERE ID = `".$id."`");
               $comment_read = mysql_query("SELECT COMMENT FROM Players WHERE ID = `".$id."`");
               echo "Reading data of user (`".$id."`): Name = `".$name_read."`; Comment: `".$comment_read."`";
            }
        }
    }
    mysql_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: 1) What line is triggering the error? 2) Please don't use MySQL_* functions.

Comment: and what IS the error?

Comment: I found the solution Matt. My variable $add_user_query gave me this error. I set the variable to "mysql_query(.....)", now I removed the function and left only "INSERT...". Now it works. But why additional mysql_query made my query empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the following line:

```
$add_user_query = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO Players( ID , NAME , COMMENT )VALUES('123','Bob','Bob's comment')" );
```

Try modifing (just for testing purposes) as follows:

```
$add_user_query = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO Players( ID , NAME , COMMENT )VALUES('123','Bob','Bob comment')" );
```

If you get it working with this, means that 'Bob's comment' was the problem, the quote after the Bob was causing it.